# For the Chrony refclock directive, how is the precision option used?

Tags: linux, timekeeping

The man page says the precision of the reference clock has units of seconds. What do those seconds measure?

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) But your question does not belong to Raspberry Pi. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Answer (score -1):

its the difference between the reference time and the system time